# How insert meta data and url with brand name

Tags: php, opencart

actually i want to add metadata for my sitemap page in opencart, so how i can add title description and keywords in sitemap page, is there any code to add in that page please?

My site title tag look like this `<title></title>` when I see my sitemap page and see in view source then i see this tag without any word so i want to add some title between that tag

**2nd question about**

I need to change url from

> Mysite.com/productname

To

> Mysite.com/category/brand/productname

Comment: Sorry, but there is just not enough information here and no evidence that you have tried anything yourself. Read http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ and learn how to ask a question properly, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: actually i want to add metadata for my sitemap page in opencart, so how i can add title description and keywords in sitemap page, is there any code to add in that page please?

Comment: What Dave said is that if you don't seam to be trying to solve your own problem it is unlikely that we can solve it for you. We don't have enough info to start helping you and you haven't read enough about how approach your task.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. You need to re-word the question and bother searching this site.

```
OpenCart Admin -> Catalog -> Categories -> Name -> Data Tab -> SEO Keyword:
```

brand/category (example)
oasis/shoes

```
OpenCart Admin -> Catalog -> Products -> Name -> Data Tab -> SEO Keyword:
```

??-the-product-name (product ID)

56-red-trainers

Nginx: (.htaccess for Apache similar, also with Apache .htaccess this is already standard after enabling Opencart SEO Urls, nginx requires manual work)

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /var/www/www.site.com/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @opencart;
        # cat
        rewrite ^/oasis/shoes?$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=1 last;

        # product
        rewrite ^/oasis/shoes/(.*)$ /index.php?route=product/product&path=2&product_id=$1 last;
    }
    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?route=$1 last;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }         
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|ini|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Makes URLS

```
site.com/oasis/shoes
site.com/oasis/shoes/56-red-trainers
```